# Where does SerializeObject.WriteSettings write the file? (path)

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have trouble finding the file on my phone. I want to have a desktop application that can read the file I'm saving with my phone (accelerometer data), and because I'm very new to android development I decided that easiest way would be just finding it in the filesystem and then opening it on my desktop via:

```
 SerializeObject.ReadSettings(this, "activityLibrary.dat");
```

I'm saving the file in my app through:

```
 SerializeObject.WriteSettings(this, ser, "activityLibrary.dat");
```

I tried searching the filesystem with ES Explorer app but it did not find my file. Tried with windows search as well. Anyone can help out? Or suggest a different, simple to understand way of moving this file between my phone and desktop?

EDIT:

I'm using this class for Object Serialization:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Base64InputStream;
import android.util.Base64OutputStream;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Take an object and serialize and then save it to preferences
 * @author John Matthews
 *
 */
public class SerializeObject {
private final static String TAG = "SerializeObject";

/**
 * Create a String from the Object using Base64 encoding
 * @param object - any Object that is Serializable
 * @return - Base64 encoded string.
 */
public static String objectToString(Serializable object) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        new ObjectOutputStream(out).writeObject(object);
        byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();

        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream b64 = new Base64OutputStream(out,0);
        b64.write(data);
        b64.close();
        out.close();

        return new String(out.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Creates a generic object that needs to be cast to its proper object
 * from a Base64 ecoded string.
 * 
 * @param encodedObject
 * @return
 */
public static Object stringToObject(String encodedObject) {
    try {
        return new ObjectInputStream(new Base64InputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedObject.getBytes()), 0)).readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Save serialized settings to a file
 * @param context
 * @param data
 */
public static void WriteSettings(Context context, String data, String filename){ 
    FileOutputStream fOut = null; 
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

    try{
        fOut = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);       
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
        osw.write(data); 
        osw.flush(); 
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Settings saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {       
        e.printStackTrace(); 
       // Toast.makeText(context, "Settings not saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    finally { 
        try { 
            if(osw!=null)
                osw.close();
            if (fOut != null)
                fOut.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
               e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}

/**
 * Read data from file and put it into a string
 * @param context
 * @param filename - fully qualified string name
 * @return
 */
public static String ReadSettings(Context context, String filename){ 
    StringBuffer dataBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    try{
        // open the file for reading
        InputStream instream = context.openFileInput(filename);
        // if file the available for reading
        if (instream != null) {
            // prepare the file for reading
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

            String newLine;
            // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
            while (( newLine = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                // do something with the settings from the file
                dataBuffer.append(newLine);
            }
            // close the file again
            instream.close();
        }

    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException f) {
        // do something if the myfilename.txt does not exits
        Log.e(TAG, "FileNot Found in ReadSettings filename = " + filename);
        try {
            context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IO Error in ReadSettings filename = " + filename);
    }

    return dataBuffer.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: There are no Java methods in Android that start with capital letters, and there is no `WriteSettings()` method in Android in any capitalization. Perhaps you might consider either posting the code for your own `WriteSettings()` method, or changing your tags to remove `java` and add the actual programming environment that you are using.

Comment: I have added the class I'm using for serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openFileOutput` saves file in `/data/data/your.package.name/files/` directory.

Use [Context.getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) or [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to easily access file to copy to computer or mail  yourself.

Comment: @LucasSeveryn: Note that you cannot access this directory on a device, except by rooting the device or using `adb shell`. If you want to be able to transfer the file to a desktop, please use external storage.

Comment: Have you got any hints on how to save this file on external storage?